# Sequelize Connection lost - read ECONNRESET at ConnectionManager.connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to populate my database using sequelize using a payload from a webhook.

but when I am trying to send this using postman, The whole payload is not going through only a part of it is, then I am getting the following error

```
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET
    at ConnectionManager.connect (XXXX\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:112:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (XXXX\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:222:24) {       
  parent: ConnectionError: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET
      at Connection.socketError (XXXX\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1408:26)
      at Socket.<anonymous>( XXXX\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1158:16)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    code: 'ESOCKET',
    isTransient: undefined
  },
  original: ConnectionError: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET
      at Connection.socketError (XXXX\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1408:26)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (XXXX\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1158:16)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    code: 'ESOCKET',
    isTransient: undefined
  }
}
```

So my database is only getting the order details and the first item.

my sequelize connections is

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
  host,
  dialect: 'mssql',
  port:1434,
  dialectOptions: {
    options: {
      encrypt: true,
      packetSize: 32768
      
    }
  }
});
```

I have tried changing the `packetSize` as well, but I am still getting the same error.